# Get google+ user profile in node using just access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to get the user profile details in Node.

The flow is such that I have a mobile app that generates the token for me (by authenticating through Google plus native SDK), then I send the token to my node server and I want to get the details about the user from Google. I tried the following (assuming I have the `access_token` from the client):

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=' + access_token, function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) return callback(err);

  if (res.statusCode != 200) {
    return callback(new Error('Invalid access token: ' + body));
  }
  else {
    var me;
    try { me = JSON.parse(body);}

    catch (e) {
      return callback(new Error('Unable to parse user data: ' + e.toString()));
    }

    console.log('user profile:', me);
  }
});
```

This works, but sometimes I get bad response like null `displayName` field, null `email` (even though I have the scope) and it's unreliable overall.

I have tried using [Google API Node module](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) but the flow there assumes I need to get token and is unnecessarily complicated.

Other than that, I don't understand the difference between Google's API versions and don't know when to use what.

**EDIT**

It seems that the problem with null `displayName` field only happens with tokens that were generated through the iOS SDK. Tokens generated with Android SDK are fine and calling the API with them resolves in `displayName`. I tried taking the iOS token and calling the following API :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=...
```

I got a `displayName` in the result, but after a couple of calls from my server I got

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was isolated to tokens generated by my IOS users only.

It seems that the token I was getting through the IOS SDK was bad for using with the API call I mentioned in my question (`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo`). Tokens generated by the Android SDK were working okay with the mentioned call.

So to find a common ground, I had to use the following API call from my server:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=...
```

You should get an object similar like this one (omitted the personal fields):

```
{
  kind:"plus#person",
  etag:"...",
  gender:"male",
  emails:[
    {
      value:"...",
      type:"account"
    }
  ],
  urls:[
    {
      value:"...",
      label:"Buzz"
    }
  ],
  objectType:"person",
  id:"...",
  displayName:"...",
  name:{
    familyName:"...",
    givenName:"..."
  },
  url:"...",
  image:{
    url:"..."
  },
  isPlusUser:true,
  language:"en",
  ageRange:{
    min:21
  },
  verified:false,
  cover:{
    layout:"banner",
    coverPhoto:{
      url:"...",
      height:626,
      width:940
    },
    coverInfo:{
      topImageOffset:0,
      leftImageOffset:0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i also getting access token form android app need to get user details using access token  in node js but not getting. can you please provide your script.